# Convert Avro Schema to JSON payload with values

Tags: java, json, avro

I have an org.apache.avro.Schema object. And I need to create a JSON complete payload with values in fields.
I'd rather say I have the solution for this using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224964/how-to-create-a-valid-json-example-from-avro-schema)

BUT

logic in *RandomData.generate* method is pretty hard to understand, debug since it uses the recursion: **private Object generate(Schema schema, Random random, int d)**

Does anybody have any other implementation to achieve the goal in more readable way? I'll take a look into other solutions except RandomData implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using Python, there was a recent addition to do what I think you are looking for. You should be able to `pip install fastavro` and then run something like the following script:

```py
from fastavro import json_writer
from fastavro.utils import generate_many
from io import StringIO

schema = {
    "namespace": "my.test",
    "name": "example_value_schema",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "field",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "int",
                {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "my_field_type2",
                    "fields": [
                        {"name": "subfield", "type": "string"},
                        {"name": "bytes_field", "type": "bytes"},
                        {"name": "array_field", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "string"}},
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
   ]
}

sio = StringIO()

json_writer(sio, schema, generate_many(schema, 6))

print(sio.getvalue())
```

The output of this when I ran it is the following:

```json
{"field": null}
{"field": {"int": 1903741208}}
{"field": {"my.test.my_field_type2": {"subfield": "TXJrWrluTg", "bytes_field": "\u0084\u008fEf\u0014\u00f4U\u00ba\u00f4]", "array_field": ["zdXQkoeFQv", "SCWCJmMsOd", "HeISJlaUoE", "qxptYDFfsb", "TcOiaLrXDA", "vOyWPySldE", "HOoeLYRVhS", "lUjhemxuSQ", "fiBdeeUSpZ", "AqTBRFpNoU"]}}}
{"field": null}
{"field": {"int": 1048727191}}
{"field": {"my.test.my_field_type2": {"subfield": "jzZYVZMdXq", "bytes_field": "\u0098Y\u00c5\u00f1\u0095\u009b\u00fd\u008bU]", "array_field": ["xyPsFLOhDp", "lSIWrETtvP", "NHmfWoOCGI", "iqtjfwmQNd", "hlENhjDOse", "oMQpJPkgQY", "eoIRSOydWj", "UChETKEaAk", "JlqxqDrCyH", "RyrLAxoePf"]}}}
```

You can see that for the union cases it will try to loop through the different union cases for each random record that is generated.

Comment: looks good and obviously more readable - would be useful for python solution. But I'm looking for java-based approach. Anyway, thanks for the answer!